# Remap Window shortcuts for use on a laptop

Tags: 11.04, unity, windows, keyboard

I've looked through the Compiz Settings, but since I am on a laptop, I can't use the numpad shortcuts for Window Placement.

How can I remap this to be something like Super-Left, Super Right, Super-Right-Up, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the Compiz Settings manager, go to Grid (under Window Management) and configure each keyboard shortcut from there.

Click on the shortcut you want to change, then click on Grab Key Combination, type the combination you want and click OK.

Something like Super-left etc. might be taken for something else though - which is why I'm using the same shortcuts as I use on OS X (with SizeUp), like this:

```
Ctrl-Super-Alt-Left -> Place left
Ctrl-Super-Alt-Right -> Place right
```

etc. etc.